# Ошибка сегментации при триангуляции большой сети в OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Мне необходимо построить триангуляционную сеть для очень большого количества уникальных точек - в моём примере, около 270000000 (270 миллионов) точек.

Для построения триангуляционной сети я использую класс [cv::Subdiv2D](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d5b/group__imgproc__subdiv2d.html).

В процессе добавления точек в триангуляционную сеть приложение завершается с `segmentation fault`(`SIGSEGV`) на моменте добавления точки № 178956970.

При дальнейшей отладке выяснилось:

1. Объема RAM+swap на моём ПК достаточно (нужно около 40 Гб);
2. Триангуляционная сеть из 178956969 точек, возвращаемая методом getTriangleList() состоит из 357913940 треугольников (что чуть-чуть меньше 8 Гб памяти);
3. При добавлении точки 178956970 наблюдается резкое увеличение расхода памяти (до максимального значения в 40 Гб).

Измерения проводились на двух ЭВМ:

1. ПК (Debian 11; OpenCV 4.5.1): RAM 32 Гб + swap 16 Гб (максимально допустимый расход памяти 48 Гб)
2. Сервер (Astra Linux 1.6; OpenCV 2.4.9.1): RAM 256 Гб + swap 256 Гб (максимально допустимый расход памяти 512 Гб)

Потребление я проверял, отслеживая показания диспетчера задач.

Потребление на ПК (сразу перед segfault): RAM - 32 Гб; swap - ~12 Гб; итоговый расход памяти 32+12=44 Гб (заметно меньше максимально допустимого расхода; ~4 Гб расходуют сторонние программы).

Потребление на сервере (сразу перед segfault): RAM - ~40 Гб; swap - 0 Гб; итоговый расход памяти ~40 Гб (заметно меньше максимально допустимого расхода).

На обоих ЭВМ возникает указанная проблема.

Из этих показаний я делаю вывод, что памяти мне хватает (хотя уже не исключаю возможность резкого возрастания потребления памяти, которое было не видно в диспетчере).

Стек:

```
main.cpp
cv::Subdiv2D::insert(cv::Point_<float>)
cv::Subdiv2D::connectEdges(int, int)
cv::Subdiv2D::newEdge()
```

Вот код с двумя примерами (вкл./выкл. `SLOW_EXAMPLE`), на которых у меня корректно не работает opencv; ошибка (и стек) одна и та же - при добавлении в Subdiv2D точки с индексом `points[178956969]` приложение аварийно завершается:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

//#define SLOW_EXAMPLE
//#define CHECK_TRIANGLES

int main() {

#ifdef SLOW_EXAMPLE
    constexpr size_t w = 27000;
    constexpr size_t h = 27000;
#else
    constexpr size_t w = 61300;
    constexpr size_t h = 104334;
#endif

    std::cout << "OpenCV ver. " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
    const cv::Rect rect(0, 0, w, h);
    cv::Subdiv2D subdiv(rect);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;

#ifdef SLOW_EXAMPLE
    const size_t cell_size = 2;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < h; row += cell_size) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < w; col += cell_size) {
            points.emplace_back((float) col, (float) row);
        }
    }
#else
    std::srand(666);
    const size_t cell_size = 4;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < h / cell_size; row++) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < w / cell_size; col++) {
            const uint32_t x = std::rand() % cell_size;
            const uint32_t y = std::rand() % cell_size;
            points.emplace_back((float) (col * cell_size + x), (float) (row * cell_size + y));
        }
    }
#endif

    const size_t points_count = points.size();
    std::cout << points[0].x << " " << points[0].y << std::endl;
    std::cout << points[points_count - 1].x << " " << points[points_count - 1].y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "points = " << points_count << std::endl;

    auto get_triangle = [&subdiv]() {
        std::vector<cv::Vec6f> triangles;
        subdiv.getTriangleList(triangles);
        std::cout << "Triangle network: " << triangles.size() << " triangles ( "
                  << (triangles.size() * 6.0 * sizeof(float)) / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0) << " GB)" << std::endl;
    };

    for (int64_t i = 0; i < points_count; i++) {
        if (i % 50000 == 0 || i > 178950000) {
            std::cout << "\rsubdiv.insert: " << i << "/" << points_count << " ( " << (i * 100.0) / points_count << " %)          ";
            std::cout.flush();
        }
        subdiv.insert(points[i]);

#ifdef CHECK_TRIANGLES
        if (i == 178956968) { get_triangle(); }
#endif
    }
    std::cout << "\rsubdiv.insert: " << points_count << "/" << points_count << " ( 100 %)          " << std::endl;
    get_triangle();
    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Кто-нибудь знает, в OpenCV есть ограничения на размер триангуляционной сети? (В Интернете и исходниках OpenCV я такой информации не нашёл; возможно, плохо искал; за пределы диапазона [0..2^31-1] идентификаторов вершин и  рёбер графа сети, вроде, не выхожу)
2. Если кто-то с таким уже сталкивался: можно ли обойти это ограничение, оставаясь в рамках OpenCV? (потайловая обработка прямоугольника 2D-точек не годится, т.к. треугольники на краях тайлов не будут соответствовать треугольникам исходной сети, а использование перекрытия тайлов, в общем случае, не решает эту проблему).

Comment: *"приложение завершается с segmentation fault"* - показывайте приложение, приводите стек вызов при падении и т.п. *"Объема RAM+swap на моём ПК достаточно (нужно около 40 Гб)"* - неясно на чем основывается это утверждение. То, что упоминается своп, сразу наводит на размышления о жесткой нехватке памяти. ¿При большем объеме доступной памяти (допустим 1 Тб) оно по-прежнему вылетает на том же месте? ¿Каково потребление памяти в момент вылета?

Comment: Можно сделать тайловое решение. Будут гарантии что в данной группе тайлов решение точное.

Comment: А можно поподробнее про гарантии? Насколько я понимаю, для обеспечения гарантии тайловой триангуляции в общем случае необходимо выполнить 2 условия:
(1) Тайлы должны быть с перекрытием;
(2) Размер перекрытия и тайлов должен быть таким, чтобы полностью включать самый большой треугольник.
При этих 2-х условиях гарантируется равенство тайловой и нетайловой триангуляций.
Входными данными моей программы условие № 2 не гарантируется - размер треугольника может быть большим (вплоть до rect, который также может быть очень большим - 100000x100000 пикселей и даже больше).

Comment: Накрываете плоскость решёткой из квадратиков. Выбираете квадратную область составленную из квадратиков. Для точек области строите триангуляцию. Для каждого треугольника строите описанную окружность. Если она целиком внутри "квадратной области", этот треугольник будет в полной триангуляции. Анализируете сколько квадратов из области покрыто целиком такими треугольниками. В этих квадратах решение найдено. Перемещаете "квадратную область", скажем, на половину её размера. Продолжаете пока все квадратики не решены.

Answer (score 0):

Размер ограничен диапазоном int - около 2 млрд треугольников.